# TypeError: callback is not a function when removing directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, directory, fs

When I try to remove an existing directory (and its files inside) with `fs.rm('./temp/', { recursive: true, force: true });` it succesfully remove it but it throws this error:

```js
node:internal/fs/rimraf:60
    callback(err);
    ^

TypeError: callback is not a function
    at CB (node:internal/fs/rimraf:60:5)
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:188:23)
```

I have Node v16.13.2 installed. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

due to the node.js fs documentation https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsrmpath-options-callback

you must pass a callback function
`fs.rm(path[, options], callback)`

so your code will look like this:

```
fs.rm('./temp/', { recursive: true, force: true }, (error) => {
    //you can handle the error here
});
```